# Sweave from the command line using concordance=TRUE

Tags: command-line, sweave

I have document that uses a LaTeX Beamer template and passes this code around the beginning of the actual document

```
\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
```

The document compiles just fine using RStudio (0.97.248) with R-2.15.2. After I finish composition, to insure reproducibility, I like to generate the entire analysis from a cmd file (and use ghostscript to compress the PDF).
The relevant parts are

```
R CMD Sweave MyDoc
pdflatex MyDoc
bibtex MyDoc
pdflatex MyDoc
pdflatex MyDoc
```

This fails with the error message

```
 ! LaTeX Error: File `MyDoc-concordance.tex' not found.
```

Which suggests that Sweave is not generating the concordance from the command line. A can't find a command line switch and my Google searches have not been helpful... I would greatly appreciate any pointers...

Comment: For a minute I thought it would be simply a matter of `R CMD Sweave MyDoc.Rnw --options=concordance=TRUE`. But it is not. I cannot find a way on the command line to create the concordance file either. Anyone have a trick to do this?

Comment: HAve you tried running `pdflatex --shell-escape MyDoc`?

Comment: I have been using RStudio lately as well as building from shell scripts. Yihui Xie suggest that I use    


\begin document
%\VignetteEngine{knitr::knitr}



instead of the \SweaveOpt line

My scripts work now

Comment: sorry about the formatting. My attempts at markdown linebreaks didn't work and they limit the time one can try

Answer (score 4):

Typically you wil run into this problem when parsing .Rnw files on the command line that were first created in RStudio. The RStudio Sweave template has the `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}` option as a default in the .Rnw file.

This seems to be an issue with Sweave that has not [had much attention](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51621/adjust-line-numbers-in-error-messages). Occasionally I run into this when working on the command line and the only work-around I have found is to set:

```
\SweaveOpts{concordance=FALSE}
```

in the file itself, delete all temporary latex and then run `R CMD Sweave` again to create a new .tex file. The resulting file will work with either `pdflatex` or `xelatex`.

Apparently it is not possible to pass the request for a concordance file to Sweave (I tried `R CMD Sweave MyDoc.Rnw --options=concordance=TRUE` as I mentioned in the comments).